# Fast way to export large amount of data in "Table" format

Tags: performance-tuning, export, list-manipulation, packed-arrays

I have about a million 3D points, say

`data = Table[{1. x, 1. y, 0.}, {x, 1000}, {y, 10^3}]~Flatten~1;`

I want to visualize them, but `Graphics3D@Point@data` or `ListPointPlot3D@data` are too slow.

MeshLab or CloudCompare can do it, but I need to export it in some way to get it there.
It can read ".txt" files with the "Table" format that Mathematica produces, but that takes a very long time to write:

`AbsoluteTiming@Export["test 1mio points.txt", data, "Table"]`

`{23.9979, "test 1mio points.txt"}`

CSV file writing is not much faster. It doesn't look like there is a general bottleneck in converting numbers to text format, as '.m' is written quite quickly:

`AbsoluteTiming@Export["test 1mio points.m", data]`

`{1.92666, "test 1mio points.m"}`

but MeshLab cannot handle it.

Any alternatives? Is there a way I can convert a list of points to a `GraphicsComplex` or `Mesh` or so and then export that in some format (that might be faster).

Comment: Are there any other formats that MeshLab can read?  If so check these against the formats that *Mathematica* can export. There may be some binary formats that overlap.

Comment: It should be trivial to write something that takes a 2D array and writes such a file in C and then integrate this via LibraryLink with WL. I am just hoping somebody has done this.

Comment: PLY and STL, and acutally also obj (by just specifying only 'v' elements) should support points, but `Export["test.ply", Point[RandomReal[1., {10, 3}]]]` fails.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I started working on a package and LinkedLibrary achieving significant speedups with this job:

```
data = Table[{1. x, 1. y, 0.}, {x, 1000}, {y, 10^3}]~Flatten~1;
<< ExportTable`
AbsoluteTiming@ExportTable["test 1mio points.txt", data]
```

`{0.0381513, Null}`

You can find it here: https://github.com/Masterxilo/ExportTable

Comment: Does not work in MMA 11.2 (Win 7 X64) as of this moment. Don't know why. Keep getting LibraryFunction::libload: The function ExportTableG was not loaded from the file ExportTable.dll. LibraryFunction::libload: The function ExportTableFixedE was not loaded from the file ExportTable.dll. and ExportTable::initfail: Failed to initialize.

Comment: Could not be imported on v. 11.3 (MacOS v.10.13)

Answer (score 6):

Here's an alternative: The package https://github.com/Masterxilo/PLYExport implements exporting of Points in PLY format, and extends Export with `{"PLY", "BinaryFormat" -> True}` to use it, allowing to also export lots of points very quickly:

```
data = RandomReal[1., {10^6, 3}];
(*Graphics3D@Point[data]*)(*don't do this for large n: Use MeshLab or CloudCompare*)
AbsoluteTiming@
 Export["test 1 mio points.ply", 
  Graphics3D@Point[data], {"PLY", "BinaryFormat" -> True}]
```

`{0.308942, Null}`

Comment: Can you provide a link to what "PLY" format is, exactly? Looks like you only use it here with a list-of-lists, and nothing more complex than that, but can it work for that? Can you please clarify this, if you are able to?

Comment: @CATrevillian https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLY_(file_format)

Answer (score 3):

Not very fast, but acceptable.

```
data = RandomReal[1, {10^5, 3}];
Export["test1.txt", data, "Table"] // AbsoluteTiming

AbsoluteTiming[
 str = Row[#, "\t"] & /@ data // Column // NumberForm[AccountingForm@#, 16] & // ToString;
 Export["test2.txt", str, "String"]
 ]

Equal @@ (ReadList[#, {Number,Number,Number}] & /@ {"test1.txt","test2.txt"}) // AbsoluteTiming
```

I also noticed that the same code version 11.2 more slowly than 11.1
[image]